# Output of pywt.dwt

Tags: wavelet, dwt, pywavelets

I am using 'dwt' function and I can't understand what the values in the approximation and detail lists actually represent. I have read that in each level the function uses high pass filters and low pass filters for the approximation and detail values. But I still didn't understand what these coefficients values represent and what are the units.

Comment: This is really just asking "what is the DWT? What do its coefficients represent?", so:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discrete wavelet transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29138/discrete-wavelet-transform)